# Checking for block blob existence fails

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Storage to store some files on Azure platform, using using the new version 4.X of [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net) Nuget package to interact with the storage.

I use a full uri with SAS key to connect to my container:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?sr=c&si=all-rights&sig=mykey");
var container = new CloudBlobContainer(uri);
```

The policy *"all-rights"* is configured in Azure Storage and provides me with all rights on the container.

The upload of the file works well

```
var myBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("desert.jpg");
myBlob.UploadFromFile(@"path\to\desert.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

When I try to check for blob existence:

```
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("desert.jpg");
var exists = blob.Exists();
```

It works like a charm when the blob named "desert.jpg" does not exists, **but I get an exception when the blob does exists:**

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Blob type of the blob reference doesn't match blob type of the blob.
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobSharedImpl.UpdateAfterFetchAttributes(BlobAttributes attributes, HttpWebResponse response, Boolean ignoreMD5)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobSharedImpl.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.Exists(Boolean primaryOnly, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.Exists(BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
>      at AzureStorage.Program.Main() in c:\Users\RMagny\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AzureStorage\AzureStorage\Program.cs:line 16
>   Request Information
>   RequestID:8ab1351a-1c66-4193-ad54-bbcaf2a20132
>   RequestDate:Thu, 31 Jul 2014 13:54:20 GMT
>   StatusMessage:OK

**Is it the right way to check for blob existence with the latest version of the library?**

I wrote this kind of code when I was on the previous 3.2.1 version of the Nuget package, and it worked just fine.

I don't know if I'm facing a bug in the library, or if there are new paradigms to use for this.

By the way, it seems I have the same issues with all methods to get/set the properties of the blob (methods `SetProperties()` and `FetchProperties()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by how your SAS token was generated. It does not contain the sv parameter, which causes the request to be processed using a very old Azure Storage Services version. And every version of Azure Storage Client Library is tied to a specific version of Azure Storage Services, which leads to the issue you are experiencing. For more information on versioning, please refer to [Versioning for the Azure Storage Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894041.aspx).

I would recommend upgrading to a newer SAS token version by either generating it using Azure Storage Client Library or using a newer version of your favorite explorer application.

Comment: I get the exact same error when using GetPageBlobReference(). And when using GetBlobReferenceFromServer(), it just freezes, and eventually gives me a StorageException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object'

Comment: How are you creating the SAS token? In the URI you shared above, I am not seeing an sv parameter, which defines the SAS version to use for authentication and authorization.

Comment: I'm using [Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) tool version 4.0.0.10 to generate my SAS key. I don't know any other tool, and I prefer not to create this by code if possible. Could my problem come from missing parameters in the SAS uri?

Comment: Thank you for the details. I was able to reproduce the issue now. And yes, the problem is caused by how the SAS token was generated. Azure Storage Explorer 4.0 uses a very old SAS version, which causes Azure Storage Blob Service to return the response in a format that the current version of Azure Storage Client Library does not understand. I will update my response with more details.

Comment: I used version 6 (preview) of my tool, generating a new SAS uri, and it worked as expected!